# Is there a Linux C compiler that doesn't name the output a.out?

Tags: c, compilation

I find a.out to be a tedious name for a file, and I am not interested in either the `-o` flag to rename output or any makefile when my build process is currently as clean as `flex tfm.l; gcc lex.tfm.c`.

Microsoft's `cl` compiler makes `lex.tfm.exe` by default. I know .exe wouldn't be applied on Linux, but is there any compiler that has similarly dropped this antiquated `a.out`? Or a pragma that would push the output name?

Comment: I do not think so, because the *blessed* way is to hide those details under in a makefile or just rely on the default rules. If you have a `foo.c` file in current folder, `make foo` will build the executable...

Comment: I find it odd that completely replacing your compiler (possibly with one that would end up performing far worse) is a more acceptable solution than `-o`, which you'd almost always want to use anyways, regardless of the default name your compiler uses. Most projects want a clean executable name, other than what the compiler decides.

Comment: Non-antiquated development tends to involve a programming IDE where you simply pick the executable name. Unless you have specialized requirements, then console commands and make files belong to the previous millennium.

Comment: Why do you care about the default name for the output file? Do you consider `lex.tfm.exe` a good name for the resulting executable on Windows? I think the `lex.` part is irrelevant to a user of the program, and I would prefer `tfm.exe`. So there is a good reason to use `-o` anyway.

Comment: Output of c compiler may be of different kind : preprocessed file, object file, executable file depending on the input file which may be more than one.

Comment: Why? And how is `lex.tfm` any less "tedious" (it is certainly more _arcane_.  I am not sure what the objection is or in what way it is "antiquated" rather then just _convention_.  The question has no technical merit - it is an irrelevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Posix standard requires that the default executable filename be `a.out`. I think any reputable C compiler designed to run on a Unix(-like) operating system will respect that standard, even if it offends the aesthetic sensibilities of some users, so you're unlikely to find the compiler you are looking for.

However, if it is that simple to build your executable, you can use `make` without creating a makefile:

```sh
$ # No makefile:
$ ls
tfm.l
$ # Default build recipe:
$ make tfm
lex  -t tfm.l > tfm.c
cc    -c -o tfm.o tfm.c
cc   tfm.o   -o tfm
rm tfm.o tfm.c
$ # Executable created with name 'tfm'
$ ls
tfm  tfm.l
```

Not that I'd necessarily recommend doing that, but it is convenient for quick compiles. I prefer to add warning options to the compile line, so the startup script for my real shell sessions exports appropriate definitions of `CFLAGS` and some environment variables used by `make`.

Comment: I use `make` without a makefile all the time for one-off compilations.  I even add `CFLAGS` definitions to the `make` command line at times, though that kind of moots the purpose.  But the other point to be made here is that `make` is a very useful tool, and one of things it is excellent for is to relieve any tedium involved in specifying compiler command-line options in builds that you are prone to repeat (via putting them in a makefile).

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yeah, me too. My standard environment defines CFLAGS (amongst other things) to make it work better for me. But I didn't really want to get into all of that.